# get the most evenly distributed entries in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

my problem is the following:
I got a `data.frame` in R which contains coordinates, e.g.

```
SNP1  chr1  123456  
SNP2  chr1  156895  
SNP3  chr1  550000  
...
```

Now I want to specify a region (e.g. chr1:100000-500000) and a number of `SNP`s (`n`) and find those `n` `SNP`s in that region that are most evenly distributed in that region.

I have a script that can divide the region into `n-1` pieces and select the SNPs that are closest to the borders of the pieces. It can also exclude `SNP`s that are named twice and get the next closest `SNP` but still there might be a better solution for selecting them evenly distributed (maybe by somehow maximizing the total distance between them but the total number of `SNP`s is quite high?).

Comment: Can you provide some [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) data and code?  maybe show us what your script does?  the `"data.frame"` you've shown doesn't make this question easy to understand or answer.

Comment: In order to determine what the best definition of "evenly distributed" is, we'd need to know why you're looking for evenly distributed SNPs in the first place (I assume it has something to do with linkage).

Comment: @Seth: That wouldn't work if the data were anything but uniformly distributed, and could come very far from working if the density is very inconsistent.